# JavaFX animation not working

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am trying to make an application where an object moves across the screen, only changing its x value. I am not getting any errors but it is not working when I run it. the objects are showing but the rectangle is not animating. I am not sure what to do

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private BorderPane root;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    private Rectangle player;
    private Circle circles;
    private Button up, down;
    private Timeline timer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        stage = primaryStage;
        root = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500); //width and height of application
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Hoop runner");  //text for the title bar of the window

        scene.getStylesheets().add("hoop.css");

        anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.setMaxHeight(500);
        anchorPane.setMinHeight(500);
        anchorPane.setMinWidth(600);
        anchorPane.setMaxWidth(600);
        player = new Rectangle();
        circles = new Circle();
        up = new Button("˄");
        down = new Button("˅");


        root.setCenter(new VBox(new VBox(circles),
                new HBox(player)));

        root.setCenter(anchorPane);

        player.setX(5);
        player.setY(380);
        player.setHeight(80);
        player.setWidth(120);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(player);

        timer = new Timeline(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        timer.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        timer.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.INDEFINITE, event -> maverick()));


        timer.play();







        stage.show();




    }

    private void  maverick() {




            timer.play();
            System.out.println("hi");
            player.setX(player.getX() + 2);
            timer.play();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `setTranslateX` instead of `setX` if you want to position or animate Nodes.
- Change `timer = new Timeline(Animation.INDEFINITE)` to `timer = new Timeline()`.
- Change `new KeyFrame(Duration.INDEFINITE, event -> maverick())` to `new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), event -> maverick())` (for example).

A KeyFrame has to have a point in time. If, like the example, you use 500ms, then the KeyFrame's EventHandler will get called after 500ms. Since your TimeLine has a cycleCount of INDEFINITE, it will loop and execute the KeyFrame every 500ms.

Comment: After making the changes above my object was able to move once but then stopped after that. How do I make it continue to move?

Comment: Did you remove `timer.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);` ? You shouldn't. That's still needed to tell the timeline to loop, so the keyframe occurs every 500ms, not just once after 500ms.